# Should Kafka Producer be reused or short-lived?

Tags: java, junit, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a test that uses EmbededKafka.

```
@Slf4j
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(
        partitions = 1,
        brokerProperties = {
                "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092",
                "port=9092"
        })
public class MyTest {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("producerFactory")
    private ProducerFactory<String, MyData> producerFactory;

    @Test
    public void test() }
        sendMessage1();
        sendMessage2();
    }

    private void sendMessage1() {
        try (Producer<String, MyData> producer = producerFactory.createProducer()) {
            // Send the data 1 using producer
            producer.flush();
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage2() {
        try (Producer<String, MyData> producer = producerFactory.createProducer()) {
            // Send the data 2 using producer
            producer.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above, I injected the Producer factory and created short-lived Kafka producer each time a message needs to be sent. The producer is closed after data is sent.

Another idea I have is to create the producer rather than producer factory in Spring TestConfiguration and inject it into the test, so that:

```
@Slf4j
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(
        partitions = 1,
        brokerProperties = {
                "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092",
                "port=9092"
        })
public class MyTest {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("producer")
    private Producer<String, MyData> producer;

    @Test
    public void test() }
        sendMessage1();
        sendMessage2();
    }

    private void sendMessage1() {
        // Send the data 1 using injected producer to Topic A
        producer.flush();
        
    }

    private void sendMessage2() {
        // Send the data 2 using injected producer to Topic B
        producer.flush();
    }
}
```

Which one of these patterns are good practice for Kafka?

Comment: In theory unit tests should be as isolated as possible, so inject the factory. Integration tests can bend these rules if it saves time, so inject the producer if it helps. In practice, I'm not sure that there will be any real difference.